# WP is ignoring .htaccess rewritten URL

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite

I have two domains being served from the same WP install. *edit: **not** multi-site*

In `wp-config.php` I have `define('WP_SITEURL', "http://$hostname/wordpress");` etc.

The two domains will have similar content, but we want to be able to have them at the same path, e.g. `domain1.com/about-us` and `domain2.com/about-us`.

I've therefore set up these two pages `\dom1\about-us` and `\dom2\about-us`, and in my `.htaccess` I have:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} dom1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^((about\-us|etc).*) /dom1/$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} dom2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^((about\-us|etc).*) /dom2/$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I get *(edit: WordPress)* 404 error pages for the above URLs. I've added `print_r($_SERVER);` in my 404 template and get the following (simplified output).

```
Array
(
[REQUEST_URI] => /about-us/
[REDIRECT_REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
[REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
[HTTP_HOST] => dom1.dev
[SERVER_NAME] => dom1.dev
[REDIRECT_URL] => /dom1/about-us/
[QUERY_STRING] => 
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
[PHP_SELF] => /index.php
...
)
```

Doesn't that mean that the rewrite has worked, but WP is not using it?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are running multisite, then this shouldn't be an issue? Since each domain counts as its own site basically, then you should be able to have /about-us without needing to do anything special.

Comment: I'm not using multisite.

Comment: Check your {HTTP_HOST}  data. It should be dom1.dev instead dom1 
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} dom1.dev$ [NC]`

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} dom1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^((about\-us|etc).*) /dom1/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Your rewrite rule includes the `L` parameter, which makes it stop processing rewrites. So WordPress's rules to redirect to index.php likely never come into effect. Which means WordPress is not even being run here. The 404 is likely from the webserver saying that the file at /dom1/about-us does not exist.

Comment: [L] doesn't work quite like that actually. The error pages are from WordPress.